# How to match dates with a mm/dd/yyyy format with specific symbols separating the sections?

Tags: javascript, regex, date

So I know how to make it so any symbol is accepted in a certain place, but how would I use regex to match to dates like this:

```
12-12-1212
12.12.1212
12/12/1212
```

But NOT match to dates using any other symbols like this:

```
12~12~1212
12=12=1212
```

Comment: I'm curious why you would be regex-parsing this and not using something like `Date.parse('12-12-1212')` ?

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing, actually.

Comment: This will help you tons, then: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date There should be methods there to help you turn strings into Date objects.

Comment: Also take a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/); very handy for dealing with dates.

Comment: As others mentionned, there are better ways to deal with dates. To answer your question, you could use character classes like so: [`^\d+[-./]\d+[-./]\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/xF7eT6/1)

Comment: @pjmorse—because parsing of strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is largely implementation dependent and strongly recommended against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

```regex
(?:0[1-9]|1[012])([-.\/])(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])\1(?:[0-9]{4})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- matches the sub strings that resemble dates in a format `mm-dd-yyyy`
- allows the separator to be one `-`, `.`, `/`
- requires both separators to be identical
- validates the month is only in the range 01-12
- validates the day can only be in the range 01-31

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/mT0kE8/2

**Sample text**

```
mm-dd-yyyy

12-12-1212
12.12.1212
12/12/1212
But NOT match to dates using any other symbols like this:

12~12~1212
12=12=1212
```

**Sample Matches**

- Capture group 0 gets  the entire date
- Capture group 1 gets the separator to ensure they're the same

```
[0][0] = 12-12-1212
[0][1] = -

[1][0] = 12.12.1212
[1][1] = .

[2][0] = 12/12/1212
[2][1] = /
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    0                        '0'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        '1'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [012]                    any character of: '0', '1', '2'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-.\/]                   any character of: '-', '.', '\/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    0                        '0'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-2]                    any character of: '1' to '2'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    3                        '3'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [01]                     any character of: '0', '1'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{4}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (4 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but rather than test the format then test for validity, an alternative is to parse the string to a date and see if it's valid.

The parser can allow the date in a format m/d/y and restrict the separators to period (.), dash (-) or forward slash (/) by splitting on the required character and testing that the resulting values generate a valid date.

If you really want to test for two digit day and month and 4 digit year, then the validation test can be combined with a very simple regular expression. But strictness generally isn't warranted, 3/4/2016 is just as valid as 03/04/2016.

So you kill 3 birds with one stone: valid string, valid values and get a Date object in return.

e.g.

```js
/* Parse date string in format mm/dd/yyyy
** @param {string} s - string to parse
** @returns {Date} date resulting from parsing string. If values
** are out of range or format is wrong, returns an invalid date
*/
function parseMDY(s) {
  if (!/\d\d[\.\-\/]\d\d[\.\-\/]\d{4}/.test(s)) return new Date(NaN);
  var b = s.split(/[\.\-\/]/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[0], b[1]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[0]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

['06.15.2016','06/15/2016','06-15-2016',
 '6.15.216','06=15=2016','26.15.2016'].forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(s + ': ' + parseMDY(s));
});
```